# How to use a single route in different contexts?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

In Nuxt, I have an admin dashboard with a special layout (sidebar), where I use `<NuxtChild>` to render child routes:

**Admin.vue**

```
<NuxtChild :key="$route.path" />
```

**Routes (simplified):**

```
{
        path: "/admin",
        name: "admin",
        component: Admin,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/admin/event/create',
                name: 'EventCreate',
                component: EventCreate,
                props: true
            }
            
            // many more routes...
        ]
        
}
```

Now, I want the `EventCreate` route to also be available alone, in a regular isolated context (NOT in the admin dashboard). This is simple enough with another route. This works fine:

```
{
    path: '/event/create',
    name: 'EventCreate',
    component: EventCreate,
    props: true
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

My routes config file will be too messy, with duplicated routes that essentially only differ by `path`.

Note: I do not use Nuxt's standard file-based routing. Instead all of my route's are defined in one central config file (for many reasons, and my preference). This is done using the Nuxt-Community router library: https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module. The end result is essentially how Vue-Router works (ie routes defined in a config file).

**QUESTION:**
Is there a way to define a route once, and have it apply to different contexts (alone or as a child inside another route)?

On a higher level perhaps there's a better way to handle this context switching (plain page vs child-inside-dashboard). In any case, `<NuxtChild>` works well aside from this, and I wanted to keep using it.

Any suggestions; different idea?

Comment: Route definition is an object. You can assign it to a variable and use several times if you need

Comment: @EstusFlask Wow you're so right; this opens doors now!

Comment: It works: I declare a object somewhere that holds shared values, like so: `const MyEventCreateRoute = { component: EventCreate, props: true }`. Then in any route I use it where needed with spread operator: `{ path: '/admin/event/create', name: 'EventCreateAdmin', ...MyEventCreateRoute }`. It still requires two route instances (dashboard and non-dashboard), but it's less lines and duplication.

Answer (score 0):

it's easy you can use [`alias`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html) option of `vue-router`:

```js
{
        path: "/admin",
        name: "admin",
        component: Admin,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'event/create', // not repeat path from root
                alias: ['/event/create'],
                name: 'EventCreate',
                component: EventCreate,
                props: true
            }
            
            // many more routes...
        ]
        
}
```

> and one more note never use a path that starts with `/` and repeat the parent path in `children` it doesn't work at all it's verbose, confusing and potentially error-prone

Comment: Well this renders 2 routes the same way. Instead I need the opposite, like this: (A) `/event/create`: renders as single page (not admin dashboard), (B) `/admin/event/create`: renders as a child in admin dashboard.

Comment: if so you can reverse declare it in children and alias to root. I will update the answer

Comment: I've tried this out and it still renders `/event/create` inside of the admin dashboard. This does make sense since both path and alias are inside `children`. Maybe pure Vue-Router has different behaviour, and Nuxt is likely taking the blunt approach ie "anything in children shall render in `<NuxtChild>`".

Comment: if so then there seems to be no choice but to accept multiple declarations. I have a question why don't you use dynamic loading for components?

Comment: I have that on my radar; will implement later. FYI, my app gets compiled into mobile native builds for app stores. This essentially bundles everything at once, so dynamic loading is not needed. For the web app client, it makes sense.

Comment: if you don't dynamically load the app will be slow because it takes a lot of unnecessary coding time

Answer (score 0):

### Share route properties with an object

Based on comment by @Estus Flask, here's one way to have a cleaner routes definition:

Use a object to store shared properites, and use it in relevant routes, reducing duplication. Still, you must still have separate routes for contexts, which makes sense.

**Object to hold shared properties:**

```
const MyEventCreateRoute = {
    component: EventCreate,
    props: true,
    // other stuff
}
```

**Routes use the shared properties with spread operator:**

```
// Basic route; not in dashboard:
{
    path: '/event/create',
    name: 'EventCreate',
    ...MyEventCreateRoute
}

// Route in admin dashboard; renders inside <NuxtChild>:
{
        path: "/admin",
        name: "admin",
        component: Admin,
        children: [
            {
                path: '/admin/event/create',
                name: 'AdminEventCreate',
                ...MyEventCreateRoute
            }
        ]
}
```